# issue regarding "Python script run in VBA crashes every times"

Tags: python, excel, vba, dashboard

I was trying to run python script in VBA so that internal users can use to explore KPIs in the dashboard (excel as GUI and Python as backend).

The issue is that every time when the code runs to the last line, the spreadsheet just disappears without returning any error message, but when I run the script in PyCharm, the dashboard on Excel can got refreshed instantaneously. I really hope that I can run some help here; Highly Grateful!!!

The VBA code that I used to run python is as follows:

```
Sub RunPythonScriptWithXlwings()
' Specify the path to xlwings executable
Dim xlwingsPath As String
xlwingsPath = "C:\Users\rren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"

' Specify the path to your Python script
Dim scriptPath As String
scriptPath = "C:\Users\rren\OneDrive - MES\Desktop\Projects\52. MAR's report Python\mar_report.py"

' Construct the command to execute xlwings with the Python script
Dim command As String
command = """" & xlwingsPath & """ run """ & scriptPath & """"

' Use Shell to run the command
Shell command, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `"run"` in the `command` string for? This is neither a command line argument for python nor processed by the VBA `Shell` in a special way.

Comment: Could the shell window not be waiting till the command is completed?

Comment: Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
vCmd  = <Python execute string>
wsh.Run vCmd, windowStyle, waitOnReturn

Comment: show/print/debug the value of "command". (Excel is crashing with a stack error)

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping the window open after running the script, so you can check for any error messages:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    'run script and keep the cmd window open
    RunScript "C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe", _
              "C:\Temp\_Python\test.py", True
End Sub

'Run script `scriptPath` with executable `exePath`
'  Pass True to `keepOpen` to keep the cmd window 
'  open after the script is done
Sub RunScript(exePath As String, scriptPath As String, _
                    Optional keepOpen As Boolean = False)
    Shell "cmd.exe /" & IIf(keepOpen, "k", "c") & " """"" & _
          exePath & """ """ & scriptPath & """""", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I kept the window open, the workbook just gone without returning error message ...

Comment: I'm guessing there's not much we can do without seeing your script then...